# Why plugin ajax response is -1?

Tags: plugins, ajax

I do not know why this response me -1 always? I am using this code in my plugin file.
i want response on click p tag

```
<?php    function myajax(){ ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#testbutton").click(function(){
                     jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                        action: 'stravyfuncajax22'
                        },
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                        }
                    });
                }); 

            });
    </script><?php
    echo'
        <p id="testbutton1">click</p>';
    }

    add_shortcode("my_ajax", "myajax");


    add_action('wp_ajax_stravyfuncajax22', 'testfunc11');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_stravyfuncajax22', 'testfunc11');

    function testfunc11() {
    echo "2";
    die();
    }
?>
```

**EDIT** : added php tag now....

Comment: Looks like some of your code didn't come through.  Can you repost it?

Comment: Is that the exact code you're using? If so you're missing `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: @Soulseekah Can you please check it now///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to wordPress jedi, scribu, you can now enqueue scripts from inside the plugin handler.

http://scribu.net/wordpress/conditional-script-loading-revisited.html

you were echoing things and in shortcode handling you have to return.  i ran into some issues getting the script to work by *returning* the script, so i moved it to an external file which definitely works.

```
function myajax(){ 

    wp_enqueue_script('my-script', plugins_url('my-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    $data = array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'myscriptL10n', $data );

    $text = '<a id="testbutton">click</a>';

    return $text;
}
add_shortcode("my_ajax", "myajax");


add_action('wp_ajax_stravyfuncajax22', 'testfunc11');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_stravyfuncajax22', 'testfunc11');

function testfunc11() {
    echo "2";
    die();
}
```

and then the my-script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#testbutton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: myscriptL10n.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'stravyfuncajax22'
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

hope that helps.

**EDIT 1**
i didn't test this part ,but i think it should work for echoing a form value as the ajax response.

`
    function myajax(){

```
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script', plugins_url('my-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    $data = array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'myscriptL10n', $data );

    ob_start(); ?>

    <form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <a id="testbutton">click</a>';
    </form>

    <?php $text = ob_get_contents();

    return $text;
}
add_shortcode("my_ajax", "myajax");


add_action('wp_ajax_stravyfuncajax22', 'testfunc11');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_stravyfuncajax22', 'testfunc11');

function testfunc11() {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    echo $data['foo'];
    die();
}
```

`

new javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#testbutton").click(function(){
         data = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: myscriptL10n.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'stravyfuncajax22',
                                data: data
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: don't forget to add a nonce.  it is talked about in the link that jared gave.

Comment: can you please help me how can i pass data in arry abd get it $data = array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    );

Comment: see my update. should (in theory) pass data in $_POST

Answer (score 2):

Try JSON encoding your response before echoing it like so (don't forget the header either!).

```
function testfunc11() {
    $response = json_encode( array( 'code' => 2 ) );
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```

And then up in your JS code..

```
alert( response.code );
```

And it should show you '2'.

However, I wouldn't recommend using `jQuery.ajax`, instead I would recommend using [this method](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) which is (in my opinion) much easier to read and use.

Comment: $.post is a shorthand way of using $.ajax for POST requests, so they're very similar. $.ajax has a very more config options, and better error handling.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I just think that `$.post` is a bit easier to read and use (hence less config options :P).